# Destroying jQuery Sortable/Droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have an issue where I would like to be able to toggle the sortable plugin's behavior when the user presses a button.  IE, have a sort mode and a view mode.  I have tried to do something like this:

```
function enterEdit(){
    $('#someDiv').sortable();
} 

function enterView() {
    $('#someDiv').sortable('destroy');
}

$('#editToggle').on('click', '.toggle-button', function(e){
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if(!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            if($target[0].id == 'edit'){
                enterEdit();                    
            } else {
                enterView();
            }
            $('#editToggle').children().removeClass('active');
            $target.addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

This is what is going on.  It works when I first initialize it, and then the destory also works.  The problem is, when I then click edit again, the sortable does not reinitialize.  Has anyone ever tried this before, or have a better solution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you give each element which should be sortable a specific class and then initialize with `$('#someDiv').sortable({items: li.yourClass});`

Then you can just add and remove this class on click and the elements will be excluded or included again.

Comment: Ahh, let me give that a shot.

Comment: Alright, that works for the sortable, but now I need to do the same for the draggable.  I tried adding the 'items' option, but that didn't have the same effect as the sortable.

Comment: This did the trick.  I added a grabbable class to a handle I specified and set that as the class that you toggle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but I'm getting a little confused why there's the double check for "active" and then "id." You should also use $(this) instead of all the e.target stuff.

Anyway, check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UahYt/). It cleans up the code for what you were doing and I think it does what you want.